# Difference between SQLite and SpatiaLite?

Tags: qgis, spatialite, sqlite

I wrote telegram bot for my uni project that receives from user spatial and non-spatial data (coordinates and user identity) and puts them in an SQLite database. Then when I extract this database and import it into QGIS an error occured that says "failed to check metadata".

Is it possible that error comes from the SQLite database because my database isn't SpatiaLite when I connect it from SpatiaLite menu i.e must my database be SpatiaLite?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Googling "spatialite sqlite" is quite relevant.

Among the first results, there is the good [BostonGIS tutorial](https://www.bostongis.com/PrinterFriendly.aspx?content_name=spatialite_tut01):

> SpatiaLite is an SQLite database engine with Spatial functions added

So you would have to install the Spatialite binaries first